# Debugging "String length exceeds DDL Length" error AWS Glue

Tags: pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, ddl

I'm writing a dynamic frame to Redshift as a table and I'm getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while calling o3225.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Error (code 1204) while loading data into Redshift: "String length exceeds DDL length"

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("transactionId", "string", "transaction_id", "string"), ("basicChannelGroupingPath", "string", "channel_grouping", "string"))], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
 

datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = applymapping1,catalog_connection = "redshift_test", connection_options ={"preactions":"truncate table dw.table;","dbtable": "dw.table", "database": "test","postactions":post_query},redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is not happening on the AWS Glue level, it's being passed from Amazon Redshift. [Error code 1204 from Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Load_Error_Reference.html) means:

> Input data exceeded the acceptable range for the data type.

That being said, some string data you are trying to write to a Redshift table exceeds the byte size limit of the string value in the table. To resolve that, I would recommend you first check the system table [STL_LOAD_ERRORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html) and check the *raw_field_value* column to see the pre-parsing value and the string that causes the issue. After that, you could do additional pre-processing for such cases (if needed) and resolve your issue.